# No bean named 'mongoTemplate' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to springboot and mongodb and cannot find the solution for my problem. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

I am seeing this warning:

```
WARN 4960 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.example.login.User.UserRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mongoTemplate' available
```

and error:

```
ERROR 4960 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean named 'mongoTemplate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'mongoTemplate' in your configuration.
```

Here is my User.java

```
package com.example.login.User;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    // id is autogenerated
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    
    public User(String email, String firstName, String lastName, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [email=" + email + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", password=" + password
                + "]";
    }
    
    
}
```

UserController.java

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    // @Autowired
    // public UserController(UserService userService) {
    //     this.userService = userService;
    // }

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public String addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "added user with id: " + user.getId();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/getAllUsers")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/getAllUsers/{id}")
    public Optional<User> getUser(@PathVariable String id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/removeUser")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable String id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "removed user with id" + id;
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package com.example.login.User;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>{
    
}
```

LoginApplication.java

```
package com.example.login;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class,MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
public class LoginApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoginApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>login</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>login</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    

</project>
```

Comment: Why are you excluding the `MongoAutoConfiguration`? Probably the missing bean would come from there. Otherwise you have to provide a bean yourself.

Comment: Did it work? Please let us know